# Osclass 3.0 login not working

Tags: php, content-management-system, osclass

I am using oslass 3.0 for my website http://www.citybonanza.com. When the user activates his account by link in email, he can view his account. After that the user can't  login to his account.

Is there any problem with cookies ?
Anyone help please . . .

Anoop G

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the issue on localhost and print the errors, its quite hard to tell from here what exactly is going on.

Comment: Thanks user1362916 for your instruction. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

It appear some error? It works if the user click in remember the login? I think that the issue is with the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). Can you try the following code at the end of the `config.php` file?

```
session_save_path ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/oc-content/uploads/session/' );
```

Just remember to add a folder named session in the `./oc-content/uploads/` folder and make it writable.

Comment: Hi Juan, it show's a "user doesn't exist message". I tried the code you are suggested. Still the problem continues.

Comment: That's odd. In that case I don't know. Do you see that user in the manage users list in the oc-admin?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is timely for future users. I found the above did not work but it is on the right path... no pun. If you give this directive the login issues should subside:

`session_save_path ( ABS_PATH . 'oc-content/uploads/' );`